# Switch Column Placement Bootstrap 4 Using CSS

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

See Sample Code:
http://www.bootply.com/kp2Iv3uJ4j

Simply, I want to change left to right columns using only CSS. Is there any way to do this using only CSS without having to change the HTML?

For example, if there was a logo in the first column and text in the second column, can I make them switch places so to speak using only CSS?

Thank you very much for your time!

Warren

Answer (score 1):

Give the row a row-reverse as follows:

```
.row {
   flex-direction:row-reverse;
}
```

Here is the example:[Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/x7fxNRQSB5)

Or if you do want to change some HTML this would be the better option:

```
<div class="row flex-row-reverse">
  <div class="col-md-6 first">
     <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150?text=first">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 second">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150?text=second">
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is an example [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/knDylnxmV2)

Comment: @user1605822 Could you accept my answer if it solved your problem?

Comment: There is no reason for the extra CSS. Just use `flex-row-reverse` http://www.bootply.com/knDylnxmV2

Comment: @ZimSystem He wanted to only use Css and not change the Html

Comment: @ZimSystem Is this better?

Comment: Much better ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can apply on HTML `push-md-6` (left to right) and `pull-md-6` (right to left) Bootstrap classes.

On your example:

```
col-md-6 first push-md-6
col-md-6 second pull-md-6
```

or, using only your classes .first and .second

```
.first { left: 50%; }
.second { right: 50%; }
```

Comment: In Bootstrap 4.x.. the classes have changed to `pull-*-*` and `push-*-*`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 push-md-6 first">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150?text=first">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 pull-md-6 second">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150?text=second">
  </div>
</div>
```

[Updated Link](http://www.bootply.com/kp2Iv3uJ4j)